# cant click button which opens file attachment dialog

Tags: selenium, automated-tests, webdriver, selenium-webdriver

i'm usinng **selenium 2 beta**. i'm trying to click button which opens file attachment dialog. but when i click it nothing happens.

```
<input class="zf" name="Passport" id="PassportUpload" type="file" onclick="return { oRequired : {} }" maxlength="524288"> 


driver.findElement(By.name("Passport")).click();
```

using just selenium not selenium 2 i can click it easily.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the issue is only when using Internet Explorer since IE and FF handles the File Input slightly different: in FF you can click on the button or the field to invoke the Open dialog, while in IE you can click on the button or *double-click* on the field.

WebDriver using native events so it is sending a native mouse click to the File Input control which is translated to the click on the input field.

It was working in Selenium 1 because it is using the JavaScript to fire the events. To make it work in WebDriver you need to invoke the JavaScript:

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.name("Passport"));
((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", upload);
```

However the code abouve will not in Firefox, so you can use something like:

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.name("Passport"));
if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", upload);
} else {
    upload.click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try following code:

```
WebElement upload = driver.findElement(By.name("Passport"));
if (driver instanceof InternetExplorerDriver) {
    ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", upload);
} else if (driver instanceof FirefoxDriver) {
 ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click;", upload);
}else {
    upload.click();
}
```